Can I use this coupon?
I was cleaning out some junk and came across something I had forgot about.  About 15-20 years ago, I worked at La-Z-Boy for a brief amount of time.  They handed out 20% off coupons and I have one.  The coupon says 20% off for employee friends and family.    It has two blank lines that were to be filled out by the employee.  The first blank line says "issued by."  Under that, it says write in the employee name and store.  The second line says date.  Under that, it says "Expires one month from above date."  The fine print only says cannot be combined with any other discounts at the bottom.
If I were to write in my name and store, then put a date, say Jan 1st 3000, would La-Z-Boy have to honor this coupon?

england-and-wales northern-ireland
The insertion of a false date as described is forgery. This offence has a statutory definition in the Forgery and Counterfeiting Act 1981. The coupon counts as an "instrument" (since it is a document, s. 8(1)(a)) and as modified it is a "false instrument", either because it was not actually "issued by" a current employee who was authorised to to do (s.9(1)(b)) or because it was not actually issued on the given date (s.9(1)(g)). To make such a false instrument, with the intention that somebody else (= La-Z-Boy or an employee) would take it as genuine and act to their prejudice (= giving a discount when they otherwise wouldn't) is forgery. Actually using the coupon in this way, once altered, is an additional offence.
Use of the coupon may also be "fraud by false representation" under the Fraud Act 2006, s.2 by the same rationale.
Prior to these enactments, altering the coupon would still be forgery at common law for the same reasons. In R v Ritson (1869) LR 1CC 200 at 204, Justice Blackburn wrote:

When an instrument professes to be executed at a date different from that at which  it really was executed, and the false date is material to the operation of the deed, if the false date is inserted knowlingly and with a fraudulent intent, it is a forgery at common law.

He further cites a writing from Chief Baron Gilbert (1674-1726), that forgery includes

to make a man's own act appear to have been done at a time when it was not done, and by force of such a falsity to give it an operation which in truth and justice it ought not to have.

In the present instance, the coupon is clearly intended to be of limited validity in time (there is a one-month window) rather than perpetual, and it is marked as being for the benefit of employees. To add a false date when no date was given is no less a forgery than erasing an original date and substituting another. Either way the intent of the coupon's offerer is being subverted.
In scotland where "uttering" (use of a forged document) is still a common-law offence, this reasoning would apply. There is some earlier authority making a distinction between altering a document, versus creating it entirely falsely from scratch, but that was only because the latter carried the death penalty. The offence is also still made out even if the coupon is immediately rejected, or if the alteration is facially ludicrous (like an issue date in the year 3000). Excuses like this were removed in a statute of 1621 (c. 22, "Anent counterfuteing and making of fals wreatis"), which said that anyone trying to declare that he no longer stands by the false instrument could still receive "the punischement whiche is dew unto those who commit falshoode" - what matters is the offering and not the acceptance.
In practice, a criminal prosecution would not necessarily follow for someone trying to use an altered 20% off coupon, but people have certainly been prosecuted in the UK for forging coupons in general. Often this involves re-use of vouchers, or printing large numbers of vouchers with autogenerated barcodes. It should be apparent from the above how these schemes fall foul of the law regarding false instruments and fraud.

No
It needs to be issued by an employee and you aren’t one.

Not to mention the date line is most likely the date of issue which means it wouldn't be valid until the year 3000.

at least not anymore
